# Cannot delete cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

So I've created a php cookie using:

```
 setcookie("first_time");
```

on one html page and when i logout, I want to remove/delete the cookie. I have tried using

```
    setcookie("first_time","", time()-3600);
    setcookie("first_time","", -1,"/");
```

along with a whole bunch of other solutions found online but i still cant seem to delete the cookie when i log out(using google chrome to check whether the cookie is still present)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Live-inspect the HTTP header response in your browser (Firebug / DevTools etc.), not just the cookie store. And enable error_reporting.

Comment: Did you tried it with another browser?

Comment: Ive also tried with IE, but doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

Use the **exact** same code you use to set the cookie, but set the time to zero (and you can use any other content.. Even an empty content)..

If that doesn't work, you're not looking in the rigth/updated place..

JO.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `/` path when you use the `setcookie()` function.

When no value is specified, the default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set it. It can only be unsetted from that same directory.